# React native filter array returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I am trying to access key pair values on a array object and setstate but it returns undefined

when i console.log(obj) i see the values but when i try to access them it get undefined

```
const data =[
  [
      {
        "name": "chris",
        "city": "unknown",
        "code": "404",
        "zip": "345"
      },{
        "name": "kulo mike",
        "city": "america",
        "code": "210",
        "zip": "43"
      },  {
        "name": "chris smith",
        "city": "unknown",
        "code": "918",
        "zip": "89"
      },

  ]
]
```

i tried this

```
const person = data.filter(
  item =>{
    item.name == 'chris'
    console.log(item.name)
  })
```

and also this

```
const person = data.filter(
  item => item.name === 'kulo mike'
  )[0].zip
```

set state

```
this.state={
    user: person
    }
```

Comment: Notice that your data array is nested. The top level array's only child is another array, which is where the user objects are stored. Calling `data.filter` only filters through the single array.

Comment: as @FThompson said you have one extra square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array inside Array, try to convert your data to :

```js
const data =[
      {
        "name": "chris",
        "city": "unknown",
        "code": "404",
        "zip": "345"
      },{
        "name": "kulo mike",
        "city": "america",
        "code": "210",
        "zip": "43"
      },  {
        "name": "chris smith",
        "city": "unknown",
        "code": "918",
        "zip": "89"
      },

]


const user = data.filter(item => item.name === 'kulo mike')[0] 

setState({user})
```